# Should I use TCP for an online game?

Tags: c#, tcp, xna, multiplayer

I have a turn-based game in which two players may play against each others.

It's written in C# and uses XNA 4.0.

Currently multiplayer is implemented with TCP/IP. It works pretty nicely, but only if the players are within the same network and one of them knows the IP of the other.

So the question is: How should I implemented the online play for this game? Is TCP a reasonable method for connecting two random players from the opposite sides of the world without them having to deal with IP addresses and ports(or any other such technical details)?

To make this problem more challenging, I have no server for hosting the game matching service. (Well, I have an access to a virtual web server which I could use for sharing the IPs.)

To list questions:

- Does .NET offer better choice of communication method than TCP?
- What would be the best way to deal with NATs in my case?
- Is there a cheap way of getting my own server and run the TCP game matching service there?

Comment: Definitely a fan of TCP here... voting to migrate this to Programmers.SE though.

Comment: I'd say gamedev is more appropriate if anything.

Comment: @Fosco why migrate? This is a problem where factual programming answers are available.

Comment: Well, the domain of problem is rather irrelevant in my opinion. After all, it's mostly just about how to transfer a string (or a byte array) from one computer to another, through firewalls and NAT in most user-friendly way.

Comment: I believe the question is a bit erroneous. Using TCP or not does not make any difference in the issue of "connecting two players without having them deal with IP addresses and ports". You're still using an IP network and as such you're not going to be free of that problem unless you use a web server hosting an application that handles them for your players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TCP vs UDP.**

TCP is a bit slower than UDP but more failsafe.

Since your game is turn based it will probably send minimal amounts of data between the client and server and it is not really latency dependant, I would say you might aswell go for TCP.

> To make this problem more challenging, I have no server for hosting the game matching service. (Well, I have an access to a virtual web server which I could use for sharing the IPs.)

If you are going to provide your players with a server browser or similar you will need to have a centralized server, a web server with a script/application built for this would do just fine.

> - Is there a cheap way of getting my own server and run the TCP game matching service there?

A web server or similar host would do just fine and is usually cheap, what you want is:

- Function for a server to add itself to the server list.
- Function for a client to retrieve the servers on the list.

Doing web requests with C# is no problem at all, the requests could look something like:

http://www.example.com/addToServerList.php?name=MyEpicServer&ip=213.0.0.ABC (adds this server to the list)

http://www.example.com/getOnlineServers.php (returns list of all the servers)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify what kind of load and latency that is expected and tolerated.

General answer is:

- For real time games - UDP.
- For scrabble-like-games - TCP.

Use your server to share IP's as you said.

Comment: Given it's turn-based, i'd say TCP sounds about right.

Comment: @George: For turn based games you can - depending on the data even consider a Web Service or the like connected to rooms. This way you dont need to share IP's and you will be able to bypass firewalls.

Comment: As a turn-based game, low latency is not a priority.
I think I can safely say that data for each turn can easily be packed into 256 bytes.

However, should I use Web Service, wouldn't that require players to query the server for message frequently, say.. like once a second? Is there a threat of game being marked as a DoS-attack?

Comment: @Habba Civilization is turn based and it uses UDP.

Comment: In a turn based game I don't see the point of using UDP; it is unreliable and if packets are lost, the sender will never know; there is no need for speedy send of packages; reliability is a more important issue; the losing of a packet could mean losing an entire turn, whereas in games such as Call of Duty it would only mean "teleporting" a few meters instead of seeing the whole player displacement, in such a game I'd see the point of going UDP.

Answer (score 0):

Minecraft uses TCP. It's good for traffic that must be transmitted and received AND can be queued a little.

Comment: Minecraft is lousy code and should not be used as an example.

Comment: It's just a game that uses TCP. I didn't say anything else about it.

Answer (score 0):

UDP is a one way error checking. Only the receiving side check for error. This was needed with the older slow ethernet technology where a round trip to check packets is too slow.

TCP is a very reliable protocol with a handshake. So the sending side knows if the data is transmitted sucessfully. But due to the round trip, it puts a lot more overhead and lag on the transmission.

TCP also do arrange packets, which UDP also don't do.

Some games it does not mind losing packets (for example "steaming" data where objects moves around, and it will get updated the next round of packet anyway). There you can use UDP. But if it is critical to get all the data, rather go with TCP, otherwise you will spend a lot of time writing code to make sure that all the data is transmitted successfully.

The networks is quickly enough and the internet being TCP/IP I recommend TCP, except if you really need very low lattency traffic.

This website gives a good summary:
http://www.diffen.com/difference/TCP_vs_UDP

NAT: Should not be a problem just as long as your Time To Live (TTL) is big enough. Every time it get NAT, it's TTL get subtracted by one. When it is 0, it gets dropped

Comment: This is incorrect. First, UDP is as "low level" as TCP, they are both Transport Layer protocols. Second, both provide error checking by means of a 'checksum' field.